# How can I use Laravel controller function created by me in an application developed in core PHP?

Tags: php, function, class, laravel-5.3

How can I use Laravel controller function created by me in an application developed in core PHP ?. 
Actually I want to use mycontroller.php function in core php files.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a bit hard to answer since we / i cant see your laravel function and therefor can see what in there is plain PHP and what is laravel inspired PHP I mean it could just be plain PHP Laravel would be happy with that and you would be able to copy paste it directly to your core PHP script. But as i said i cant provide a more clear answer without seeing your function.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank You Anoxy, Actually I have already developed a plain PHP application. Now i want to switch this application module by module to laravel and also to production mode. So i want to create some library in laravel that in beginning can also be use in plain PHP based application.

Comment: As long as you write your functions in laravel in plain PHP you can always take them out and use them else where but when you start to use laravel function your are dependant on laravel. Please accept this answer if it helped you.